# Extract comma separated list of number or words using Java

Tags: java, string, token, extract, digits

for example with the given input message: `hello java 2017 ** 2020 world`

- When choice == 2 output `2017 , 2020`
- when choice == 3 output `hello , java , world`

Here is my program:

```
public static void print(String message, int choice){
    {    
        for (int i = 0; i < message.length();) {
            if (message.indexOf(" ") != -1) {
                System.out.print(message.substring(0, message.indexOf(" ")));
                message = message.substring(message.indexOf(" ") + 1);
                switch (choice) {
                    case 2: {
                        char c;
                        for (int k = 0; k < message.length(); k++) {
                            c = message.charAt(k);
                            if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                                System.out.print(c+" , ");
                            }break;
                        }
                    }
                    case 3: {    
                        for (int z = 0; z < message.length(); z++) {
                            char tr = message.charAt(z);
                            if (Character.isAlphabetic(tr)) {

                                System.out.print(tr);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println(message);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to do it without using `split`, `replace`, `arrays` or a `tokenizer`.

Comment: Please be more specific. Your question is very vague.

Comment: So you want to tokenize either numbers or words? Whats not working in your code?

Comment: I've edited your post for grammar and formatting.   The biggest problem remaining is that you have code, but you don't say what isn't working.   Please edit your question and say what is happening that you don't expect.

Comment: You really should be using the things you don't want to use to do this.  Why do you not want to use them?

Comment: When writing code in Java, use Java classes that already exist.  Stop attempting to reinvent the wheel, you will not succeed.

Answer (score 1):

Regex?

You can match numbers with `(\\d+)` in Java and words (assuming from your example that it will contain only alphabetical characters with `([a-zA-z]+)`

Now you can go ahead and do the following:

```
public static void print(String message, int choice) {
    switch (choice) {
        case 2:
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(message);
            while (m.find()) {
                System.out.println(m.group());
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-z]+)");
            Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(message);
            while (m2.find()) {
                System.out.println(m2.group());
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Instead of printing the groups, you can as well add them to a list for later use, etc.

However I suggest (as others did in the comments before) that you use the probably easier and faster tools Java already offers to you.

Testing the above code with your example like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "hello java 2017 ** 2020 world";
    print(s, 2);
    System.out.println();
    print(s, 3);
}
```

prints:

> 2017
>   2020
>
> hello
>   java
>   world

Again you can put those in a List or other type of collection for later use including the comma separation.